# A closed 1-form $\omega$ on a manifold $M$ is exact if and only if $\int_{S^1} f^* \omega = 0$ for every smooth map $f: S^1 \to M$

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm preparing for a qualifying exam and this is a question that was on a recent past exam. One direction is immediate; if $\omega = d \eta$ is exact then Stoke's theorem gives 
$$ \int_{S^1} f^* \omega = \int_{S^1} f^* d \eta = \int_{S^1} d f^* \eta = \int_{\partial S^1} f^* \eta =0. $$
In the other direction, I believe the hypothesis implies that $\omega$ is conservative, and one can show that conservative $1$-forms are exact. But the proofs I've seen of that result (for instance, Theorem 11.42 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*) doesn't need or assume that $\omega$ is closed. I was wondering, is there was a simpler solution perhaps the test-writers had in mind than showing every conservative $1$-form is exact when they included this extra hypothesis? So far my idea is this hypothesis gives us that $f^* \omega$ is closed for each $f$, and hence $f^* \omega$ is also exact for each $f$ since $H^1_{dR}(S^1) \cong \mathbb{R}$ has as a basis any $1$-form with nonzero integral, but this is as far as I could get.

Comment: Sure, you’re right, if you want conclude the thesis you must impose that $f^*\omega$ is closed

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $x_0\in M$, define for every $x\in M$, consider a path $c_x$ such that $c_x(0)=x_0, c_x(1)=x$ and define $g(x)=\int_0^1c_x^*\omega dt$. $g$ is well defined since $\int_S^1f^*\omega=0$ for every $f:S^1\rightarrow M$. Show that $dg=\omega$.

To show that look the situation locally, that is in a chart, to evaluate $dg$ at $v\in T_xM$, consider piecewise linear curve in the chart and directional derivatives.